# How do I make a custom context menu item in Finder?

Tags: macos

I do a lot of command line work, which involves a lot of folder navigation with `cd`.

To make my life easier, I'd love to be able to right-click on a folder in Finder and have a context menu item I could click that simply opens Terminal and `cd`s to that directory.

How would I go about this in OS X (Snow Leopard)? I'm a website developer, so familiar with programming languages and computer literate, so feel free to get technical with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the `cd` command in a new window or tab, you can simply turn on the built-in services, "New Terminal at Folder" and "New Terminal Tab at Folder", by going to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services > Files and Folders`.

If you want the `cd` command in the active window or tab, you can make a simple Automator Service.

1. In a new Automator Service, change "Service receives selected" to `folders`.
2. Add a "Run AppleScript" action.
3. Replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with the following:

   ```
   tell application "Terminal"
       reopen
       activate
       set cmd to "cd " & quoted form of posix path of input
       try
           if busy of selected tab of window 1 then error
           do script with command cmd in window 1
       on error
           do script with command cmd
       end try
   end tell
   ```
4. Save the service with whatever name you want your menu item to have, then it's ready to go.

An alternative to using a contextual menu is to just type `cd` (with a trailing space) then drag the folder to the Terminal window.

Comment: Thanks, joelseph. Yeah, I currently use the drag folder into Terminal trick, but would love to just be able to right-click on a Folder and have it open Terminal, then having to open Terminal, type `cd `, and then drag the folder. I'll give the above a go and let you know how I get on!

Answer (score 0):

If you use iTerm2 (free), you can right click > Services > New iTerm2 Window Here.